# CSS hover pseudo class word per word

Tags: css

In CSS when I use

```
p:hover {background-color: grey;}
```

it changes the whole paragraph. I want it to change a single word in that paragraph when I hover on any words in it. How can I do it ?

Comment: can you change the markup and wrap that word in a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to wrap every word manually, you can use jQuery to do it for you like below:

```
var p = $('p');
var text = p.text().split(' ');
for( var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i=i+1 ) {
    text[i] = '<mark>' + text[i] + '</mark>';
}
p.html(text.join(' '));
```

Then you make your CSS as below:

```
p mark:hover {background:yellow}
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zL2Yw/1/

Unfortunately, there's no pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your word with an inline element, e.g.

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet <mark>consectetur</mark> dolor ...
</p>
```

And change its background color when the paragraph is hovered

```
p:hover mark {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

(Feel free to use a most suitable element instead of `<mark>...</mark>`)

Comment: I don't have a particular word to highlight, every word I hover on must be highlighted